# How to add HTML to a template only when user is logged out/ not registered

Tags: plugins, shortcode, templates

I'm trying to add a login/register button to my home page only when a user is logged out. I've tried using the do_shortcode call into the relevant template: (I know there is currently no conditional to check if logged in but I just want to ensure that the shortcode actually works first of all)

```
add_shortcode('loginout_button','add_loginout_button');

function add_loginout_button {
$content = '<div style="text-align:center;background-color:#7114B7;padding:15px;border-radius:50px;margin:20px;"><a href="">
                LOGIN/REGISTER
                </a>  
                </div>';
return $content; 
}
```

which is then called using the

```
echo do_shortcode('[loginout_button']);
```

in the template, but the shortcode is not registering- it's only echoing [loginout_button]. I guess this is not the way to do it then! Do I have to use a filter and then apply_filters? It made sense in my head but I honestly now need some help with this one- thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your shortcode usage code is incorrect, correct code is:

```
echo do_shortcode('[loginout_button]');
```

Now, if you want to echo the **login/logout** button only when user is not logged in, you can use the function `is_user_logged_in()`. There are two ways to do this

1). Conditional logic inside your shortcode.

```
add_shortcode('loginout_button','add_loginout_button');
function add_loginout_button() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return '<div style="text-align:center;background-color:#7114B7;padding:15px;border-radius:50px;margin:20px;"><a href="">LOGIN/REGISTER</a></div>';
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the recommended way because you can use the shortcode anywhere and get the expected result.

2) Wrap your shortcode usage code in the conditional tag

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[loginout_button]');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy/paste right your code?

It's missing the parenthesis on add_loginout_button. It should be:

```
function add_loginout_button() {
$content = '<div style="text-align:center;background-color:#7114B7;padding:15px;border-radius:50px;margin:20px;"><a href="">
                LOGIN/REGISTER
                </a>  
                </div>';
return $content; 
}
```

This should be added on functions.php.

And you can also check if a user is logged in or not with [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/):

```
add_shortcode('loginout_button','add_loginout_button');

function add_loginout_button() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $content = '<div style="text-align:center;background-color:#7114B7;padding:15px;border-radius:50px;margin:20px;"><a href="">LOGIN/REGISTER</a></div>';
    } else {
        $content = '';
    }

    return $content; 
}
```